# Unable to send the post request in spring cloud contract

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to send a post request via `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup()` and I am getting the below error for the request. I have my contracts in Groovy file with request and response code. I am getting the 400 response below the following exception.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.organisation.online.myService.common.model.Payload, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6064493f; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.organisation.onlinebank.myService.common.model.Payload, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6064493f; line: 1, column: 1]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.performRequest(MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.java:174)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.sendRequest(MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.java:404)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.post(MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.java:590)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.post(MockMvcRequestSenderImpl.java:79)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.post(MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.java:752)
at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.post(MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.java:66)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.ContractVerifierTest.validate_should_Create_post_Request(ContractVerifierTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
```

---

At the end of above exception.. here is the following junit assertion

```
expected:<[2]00> but was:<[4]00>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[2]00> but was:<[4]00>
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.ContractVerifierTest.validate_should_Create_post_Request(ContractVerifierTest.java:28)
```

The actual payload which is sent inside the request is an interface and I know that could be the problem in creating the request payload. Other than that, I don't know how to deal with this error. Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you need to provide your custom serializer to the RestAssured lib. You can also try to pass the webcontext instead of the standalone setup. Maybe that way the serializer will be applied automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used spring framework's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to deserialize the object. Here is my implementation code.

*Write a static class with the below method.*

```
public class MappingJacksonFactory {

public static MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter create() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = converter.getObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
    SimpleModule module = new TypeModuleFactory();
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    return converter;
   }

}
```

*Use the above code inside `setMessageConverter()` method
converters.*

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new yourController()))
            .setMessageConverters(MappingJacksonFactory.create());
```